# Matplotlib: Using np.mgrid to create a cube surface plot

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I do not understand how plot_surface and np.mgrid work together to create a face.
When I try I keep getting 3 faces in the shape of a 'Z'. I would like to see a proper example of a cube to understand this better.

Comment: Look for this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44881885/python-draw-3d-cube/45094199#45094199 I may plot cube without plot_surface calls

Comment: It didn't help me figure out mgrid, but it did help me solve my problem. Thank you!

Comment: Implemented here under 2nd Update: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45254284/best-mesh-for-sphere-face-extrusions-in-python